# Facebook Social Plugins Only Loading Once Within Custom Lightbox using JQuery and .load();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to create a lightbox effect with social links (very similar to what you get when you click a Twitter profile on the website itself) but I am hitting a wall.

The issue is that when I click the link once, it loads the external page as I want it to.

BUT when I close the box, and go to re open, it only loads a direct link, rather than the plugin.

You can see the early demo here: http://maenet.co.uk/library/social-lb/exchange.html

I am pretty much sure it is down to a `fb.xfbml.parse();` issue, but I just can't get my head around it.

exchange.html

```
<div id="fb-btn">
<p id="fb-1">Click Here</p>
</div>

<div class="display" id="social-facebook"></div>

<style>
html, body {height: 100%;}
.display {display: none;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;text-align: center;background: rgba(0,0,0,1);width: 100%;height: 100%;color: white;}
</style>

<script>

$('#fb-1').click(function(){
    $('.display').html('<div class="fb">Please Wait</div>');
    $('.display').show();
    $('.display > div').load('fb-1.html');
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('social-facebook'));
});

$('.display').click(function(){
    $('.display > div').css('display','none');
    $('.display').css('display','none');
});

</script>
```

regular fb embed coding located at fb-1.html

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=209038619141340";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cheese-Sandwiches/31745757555?fref=ts" data-width="500" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cheese-Sandwiches/31745757555?fref=ts"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cheese-Sandwiches/31745757555?fref=ts">Cheese Sandwiches</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

So if you have any ideas about how to get around this, I will be eternally grateful

Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because FB is not defined in the current page.

1. Load facebook js-sdk in the current page.
2. Use the callback function for [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete) instead (something like below). This will ensure the the requested page is loaded completed and then parse is executed.

---

```
$('.display > div').load('fb-1.html', function(){
  FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('social-facebook'));
});
```

I tested this approach and it seemed to work.

Hope this helps.

PS: You can improve the code like this

```
$('.display').click(function(){
    $('.display > div').hide(); // I don't understand why you're doing this because in the next line the parent itself is being hidden anyways
    $(this).hide();
});
```